# How to launch media player?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

How can I invoke media player to play the default song from it's list on the click of a button?

```
MediaPlayerLauncher mediaPlayerLauncher = new MediaPlayerLauncher();

mediaPlayerLauncher.Media = new Uri("MyVideo.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
mediaPlayerLauncher.Location = MediaLocationType.Data;
mediaPlayerLauncher.Controls = MediaPlaybackControls.Pause | MediaPlaybackControls.Stop;
mediaPlayerLauncher.Orientation = MediaPlayerOrientation.Landscape;

mediaPlayerLauncher.Show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Read here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394004%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) About media player launcher

Comment: This program is to invoke a default video installed within our application directory but what i wanted to know is that can we just invoke the default media player to play the default song from its's library ?? If yes, Can you connect me to some of the resource for it or Explain it to me that how can we do this ?